# Notation used in the proof of $^C(^B A) \approx \ ^{C \times B}A$: $\ \ \ \Phi (f)(c,b)$ and $\big(f(c)\big)(b)$

Tags: functions, notation, cardinals

I am trying to step through a proof provided by my book of this statement:

> $^C(^B A) \approx \  ^{C \times B}A$

The author writes the following:

> Define $\Phi : \ ^C(^B A) \xrightarrow[onto]{1-1}\ ^{C \times B}A $ by saying that $\Phi (f)(c,b) = \big(f(c)\big)(b)$

I have never seen these notations before: $\Phi (f)(c,b)$ or $\big(f(c)\big)(b)$. **What do they signify**?

---

$^C(^B A)$ and $^{C \times B}A$ are both sets of functions...but I am not certain how to parse the above notation.

Focusing just on $\ ^C(^B A) $, I can decompose this set into first $^B A$, which is a set of functions from $B$ to $A$. Which I'll illustrate as $\{g_{B \to A_1}, g_{B \to A_2},...,g_{B \to A_n}\}$.

Then $\ ^C(^B A) $ is the set of functions from $C$ to $\{g_{B \to A_1}, g_{B \to A_2},...,g_{B \to A_n}\}$.

So one such function $f$ would look like: $f_1= \{\langle c_1, g_{B \to A_1} \rangle,...,\langle c_m,g_{B \to A_m} \rangle \}$

Given that $g_{B \to A_1}$ would look something like $\{\langle b_1, a_1 \rangle, ..., \langle b_p, a_p \rangle \}$, the first element of $f_1$...i.e. $\langle c_1, g_{B \to A_1} \rangle$...would look like:

$\langle c_1, \{\langle b_1, a_1 \rangle, ..., \langle b_p, a_p \rangle \} \rangle$

Thus, $f_1$ contains different variations of this.

But even after breaking this down, I still do not see what $\Phi (f)(c,b)$ is specifically referencing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the domain of $\Phi$ is ${^C}\left({^B}A\right)$, the $f$ in $\Phi(f)$ must be a function from $C$ to ${^B}A$. The codomain of $\Phi$ is ${^{C\times B}}A$, so $\Phi(f)$ must be a function from $C\times B$ to $A$; for convenience call this function $g$, so that $\Phi(f)=g:C\times B\to A$. Now we can apply this function $g$ to any $\langle c,b\rangle\in C\times B$ to get $g(c,b)\in A$. And $g$ is just a simpler name for the function $\Phi(f)$, so we can equally well write this element of $A$ as $\big(\Phi(f)\big)(c,b)$. Finally, context makes it clear that $\Phi(f)$ is a function from $C\times B$ to $A$, so we can drop one set of parentheses and write simply $\Phi(f)(c,b)$. That is, we **know** that the function $\Phi$ takes a single argument, so $f$ must be that argument, and we **know** that $\Phi(f)$ is a function that takes arguments in $C\times B$, so $\langle c,b\rangle$ must be the input to the function $\Phi(f)$.

The rest of the quoted definition tells you which function from $C\times B$ to $A$ the function $\Phi(f)$ actually is. Recall that $f$, the input to $\Phi$, must be a function from $C$ to ${^B}A$. And $c\in C$, so we can apply $f$ to $c$ to get a function $f(c)$ from $B$ to $A$. For convenience I’ll call that function $h$, so that $f(c)=h:B\to A$. Now $b\in B$, the domain of $h$, so $h(b)$ makes sense and is some element of $A$, say $a$. Finally, we can get rid of the abbreviation $h$: $h$ is just handier name for the function $f(c)$, so $h(b)=a$ is just an abbreviation for $\big(f(c)\big)(b)=a$.

To sum up, for each $f:C\to{^B}A$ we define a function $\Phi(f):C\times B\to A$ by letting $\Phi(f)$ take the ordered pair $\langle c,b\rangle\in C\times B$ to the same element of $A$ to which the function $f(c):B\to A$ takes $b$.

Comment: Lovely! One point of clarification: you write, " $h$ is just handier name for the function $f(c)$, so $h(b)=a$ is just an abbreviation for $\big(f(b)\big)(c)=a$. " Should that last bit be, instead, $\big(f(c)\big)(b)=a$?

Comment: @S.Cramer: It should indeed; thanks!

Comment: This may be a silly question, but after mulling over the author's function...the $c$ and $b$ that are part of the $\Phi$ definition are FIXED, correct? That is to say, $\Phi : \ ^C(^B A) \xrightarrow[onto]{1-1}\ ^{C \times B}A $ is, perhaps, more clearly described as $\Phi_{c,b}$. For instance, one may create a different $\Phi$ of the form $\Phi_{c',b'}$, where either $c' \neq c$ or $b' \neq b$ and this function is, generally, NOT equal to $\Phi_{c,b}$. Further, I guess the claim of the author is that REGARDLESS of the $c$ and $b$ you choose, we can still generate a bijection. Right idea?

Comment: @S.Cramer: No, absolutely not: $\langle c,b\rangle$ ranges over all of $C\times B$. $\Phi$ sends each function $f:C\to{^B}A$ to a function $\Phi(f):C\times B\to A$, and the definition tells you what this function $\Phi(f)$ does to each pair $\langle c,b\rangle\in C\times B$. There is just one function $\Phi$ here.

Comment: hmmm. Maybe I am misunderstanding. Based on your comment it seems like the following statement is what is really being said: $\forall c \in C, b \in B \Big ( \Phi(f)(c,b) = \big(f(c) \big)(b) \Big) \leftrightarrow \langle f, \Phi(f) \rangle \in \Phi$

Comment: @S.Cramer: That expression is a true statement, but it’s a backwards way of looking at what’s really going on. Remember, the whole point is to define a bijection from ${^C}\left({^B}A\right)$ to ${^{C\times B}}A$, so it would make more sense to say: $$\forall f\in{^C}\left({^B}A\right)\left(\Phi(f)=g\leftrightarrow g\in{^{C\times B}}A\land\\\forall\langle c,b\rangle\in C\times B\left[g(c,b)=\big(f(c)\big)(b)\right]\right)\,.$$

Comment: Perfect. Cheers, Sir. Thank you~~

Comment: @S.Cramer: You’re welcome.