# Prove that $\Phi$ is surjective. $\Phi: \ ^C(^B A) \to\ ^{C \times B}A $ where $\Phi (f)(c,b) = \big(f(c)\big)(b)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I would like to prove that the following function...

> $\Phi: \ ^C(^B A) \to\   ^{C \times B}A $ where $\Phi (f)(c,b) = \big(f(c)\big)(b)$

...is **surjective**. I don't believe this is useful for the task at hand, but I *have* proven that $\Phi$ is injective.

Any confusion with notation can be addressed here: [Notation used in the proof of $^C(^B A) \approx \ ^{C \times B}A$: $\ \ \ \Phi (f)(c,b)$ and $\big(f(c)\big)(b)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3992248/notation-used-in-the-proof-of-cb-a-approx-c-times-ba-phi)

---

Here is what I have so far, but I am concerned that there may be a *leap* in my logic...or at least an unacceptable degree of informality:

*Claim to Prove* - $\forall g \in \  ^{C \times B}A \Big [ \exists f \in \  ^C(^B A) \ \big [\forall c \in C, b \in B \big (g(c,b)=f(c)(b) \big) \big] \Big ]$

Consider an arbitray $g' \in \  ^{C \times B}A$.

$g' \in \  ^{C \times B}A \rightarrow \forall c \in C, b \in B \Big( 
\exists ! a \in A \big(g'(c,b)=a\big) \Big)$

Consider $c' \in C$ and $b' \in B$. Then we know that $g'(c',b')=a'$.

---

There are two families of functions relevant for this next part:

i) functions of the form... $\quad f: C \to \ ^B A$ where $\quad f \in \ ^C(^B A)$

ii) functions of the form... $\quad h: B \to \ A$ where $\quad h \in \  ^B A$

Note that for $c\in C$, $f(c)$ necessarily maps to a function of the "ii" form.

---

By definition of $^B A$, there exists at least one $h \in \  ^B A$ that maps $b'$ to $a'$. In other words, $\exists h  \in \  ^B A \Big (h(b')=a' \Big)$. Call one such function $h'$.

By definition of $^C(^B A)$, there exists at least one function in $^C(^B A)$ that maps $c'$ to $h'$. In other words, $\exists f  \in \  ^C(^B A) \Big (f(c')=h' \Big)$. Call one such function $f'$.

Therefore, we can see that the following is true: $f'(c')(b')=h'(b')=a'=g'(c',b')$.

I will refer to this block as **Procedure 1**

---

Now, the issue that I believe I am running into is that I have **only** demonstrated that a function $f$ exists that can "handle" a *single* arbitrary pair of elements from $C$ and $B$. However, what I *need* to show is that there exists an $f$ that can handle *all* pairs of elements from $C$ and $B$.

Essentially, I believe I proved:

$\forall g \in \  ^{C \times B}A \Big [  \forall c \in C, b \in B \big [\exists f \in \  ^C(^B A) \Big(g(c,b)=f(c)(b) \Big ) \ \big] \Big]$

Where I am stuck is whether or not the immediately above statement **implies** the surjective claim because of the definition of $ ^C(^B A)$. If that implication is true, I am unsure of how to formally express it.

---

Added thoughts:

It seems like for a given $g'$, I could repeat **Procedure 1** as many times as necessary using all of the different combinations of elements from $C$ and $B$. Necessarily, this would create subsets of functions from $ ^C(^B A)$ that satisfy the criteria used in Procedure 1.

For example, I would have the following sets:

$\{\text{functions in } ^C(^B A) \text{ that satisfy } c_1, b_1\}, \{\text{functions in } ^C(^B A) \text{ that satisfy } c_1, b_2\},...,\{\text{functions in } ^C(^B A) \text{ that satisfy } c_2, b_1\},...$

It seems like I could take the intersection of this family of sets and if I could prove that the resulting set is non-empty, then I would demonstrate that there is a function that satisfies the necessary criteria of $\exists f \in \ ^C(^B A) \Big [ \forall c \in C, b \in B \big (g'(c,b)=f(c)(b) \big) \Big ]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You started fine by looking at an arbitrary function from $C\times B$ to $A$, but after that you got bogged down in notation and details.

Let $f$ be any function from $C\times B$ to $A$; we want to find a function $g$ from $C$ to ${^BA}$ such that $\Phi(g)=f$. That is, for each $c\in C$ the function $g$ should pick out a whole function $h_c$ from $B$ to $A$, and there is a natural way to do that. For each $c\in C$ let

$$h_c:B\to A:b\mapsto f(c,b)\,,$$

and let

$$g:C\to{^BA}:c\mapsto h_c\,.$$

> This is a more general instance of something that you may already have seen in a more familiar setting. If $f:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R$ is a real-valued function on $\Bbb R^2$, you can define a ‘slice’ function $f_x:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R:y\mapsto f(x,y)$ for each $x\in\Bbb R$. It’s these ‘slice’ functions that you look at when you consider $f_y$, the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to $y$.

Now we need only check that $\Phi(g)=f$. This is straightforward: by definition

$$\Phi(g)(c,b)=\big(g(c)\big)(b)=h_c(b)=f(c,b)$$

for each $\langle c,b\rangle\in C\times B$, so $\Phi(g)=f$.

Comment: Perfect. Cheers~

Comment: @S.Cramer: Glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is correct, but I think your proof fails on the moment you just say $\exists h\in ^B\! A$ such that $h(b')=a'$, somehow you are missing a lot information.
Take $g\in ^{C\times B}\!\!A$ and define $f\in ^C\!\!(^B\! A)$ as $f(c):=g(c,-)\in ^B \!\!A$ for all $c\in C$ (in other words, for each $c\in C$, $f(c)$ is the function in $^BA$ that maps every $b\in B$ to $g(c,b)$). Then, by definition, $\Phi(f)(c,b)=f(c)(b)=g(c,b)$ for all $(c,b)\in C\times B$.

Two functions are equal if they map same elements to same elements, and they have same range and domain, so $ \Phi(h)=g$. Then $\Phi$ is surjective.

Note that your question is almost trivial and by definition if you don't overthink it, otherwise can seem very difficult to proof. Also note that you must start your reasoning on the "highest set" (in this case $^C(^B A)$), otherwise you won't be able to puzzle all your pieces from down to up.